# Oracle MCS cannot store pictures

Tags: android, oracle, mcs

I am trying to upload an image from my android device using oracle mobile cloud service tutorial but I am getting this error

Notifications : Context or SenderID is not valid
Got error or unexpected status code 401 for GET on uri https://trials-flipmmtrial.mobileenv.us2.oraclecloud.com:443/mobile/platform/storage/collections/FIF_UserData

I have followed the video on youtube and have configured the config.xml file also but still getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post this sort of question to the MCS OTN Forum please?  At the moment your questions don't fit the format of Stackoverflow, you're simply not providing enough detail and this requires an ongoing dialogue which Stackoverflow isn't suited to.  And second Oracle staff actively watch the OTN Forums, but not Stackoverflow.

Comment: sure I can do that

Comment: Questions has been transferred here: https://community.oracle.com/message/14045993